# Date/Time manipulation - friendly countdown string

Tags: delphi, math, datetime, timer, delphi-7

I'm building something which has a countdown to a certain date/time. I have it working - at least the Hours, Minutes, and Seconds work fine. My problem is when I try to implement Days, it does not give the correct result. I know about the DateUtils unit, but there's so much stuff there and I don't know how to do this, especially since I'm horrible at math.

I have a timer with interval at 100. Then I have a global `fDestDT` for the destination date/time to base the countdown off of. In the timer, I have a local TDateTime called `DT`. I then break it into multiple strings and put them back together into 1 'friendly' string...

```
procedure TForm1.TmrTimer(Sender: TObject);
var
  DT: TDateTime;
  D, H, N, S: String;
  Str: String;
begin
  DT:= fDestDT - Now; //fDest = destination date/time of countdown
  //Need to format only plural numbers with 's'
  D:= FormatDateTime('d', DT)+' Days';    //Get number of days
  H:= FormatDateTime('h', DT)+' Hours';   //Get number of hours
  N:= FormatDateTime('n', DT)+' Minutes'; //Get number of minutes
  S:= FormatDateTime('s', DT)+' Seconds'; //Get number of seconds
  Str:= D+', '+H+', '+N+', '+S;           //Build friendly string
  if lblTitle.Caption <> Str then
    lblTitle.Caption:= Str;               //Update caption only if it's changed
end;
```

It should come out something like...

`0 Days, 3 Hours, 1 Minute, 12 Seconds`

But instead the days are showing wrong, when the Date/Time of the countdown is on today's date, it is showing 30 Days...

`30 Days, 3 Hours, 1 Minute, 12 Seconds`

I presume that if I were to put it more than 1 month in advance, it would also not show correctly either. How do I get the number of days properly? And is there anything in the DateUtils unit that can automate most of this work better than I already am?

EDIT:
FIXED! The problem was I was stupidly subtracting with `DT:= fDestDT - Now;` which was correct in my first code snippet, but after converting to use `DateUtils.DaysBetween` instead, I needed to remove that subtraction, and just set `DT:= Now;`.

Working code:

```
procedure TForm1.TmrTimer(Sender: TObject);
var           
  DT: TDateTime;
  Days, Hours, Mins, Secs: Word;
  SDays, SHours, SMins, SSecs: String;
  Str: String;
begin     
  DT:= Now;
  Days:= DaysBetween(DT, fDestDT);
  Hours:= HoursBetween(fDestDT, DT) mod 24; // Remove total days
  Mins:= MinutesBetween(DT, fDestDT) mod 60;
  Secs := SecondsBetween(DT, fDestDT) mod 60;
  if Days =  1  then SDays:=  'Day'    else SDays:=  'Days';
  if Hours = 1  then SHours:= 'Hour'   else SHours:= 'Hours';
  if Mins =  1  then SMins:=  'Minute' else SMins:=  'Minutes';
  if Secs =  1  then SSecs:=  'Second' else SSecs:=  'Seconds';
  Str:= Format('%d '+SDays+' %d '+SHours+' %d '+SMins+' %d '+SSecs,
    [Days, Hours, Mins, Secs]);
  if lblTime.Caption <> Str then
    lblTime.Caption:= Str;
end;
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

See `DaysBetween`, `HoursBetween`, `MinutesBetween`, and `SecondsBetween` in `DateUtils`. You have to do some minor math. :)

Here's a sample console app to demonstrate:

```
program Project2;

{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

uses
  SysUtils, DateUtils;

procedure ShowTimeDiff(const StartDate, OldDate: TDateTime);
var
  Days, Hours, Mins, Secs: Word;
  OutputText: string;
begin
  Writeln(Format('Start: %s, Old: %s',
      [FormatDateTime('mm/dd/yyyy hh:nn:ss', StartDate),
      FormatDateTime('mm/dd/yyyy hh:nn:ss', OldDate)]));
  Days := DaysBetween(StartDate, OldDate);
  Hours := HoursBetween(OldDate, StartDate) mod 24; // Remove total days
  Mins := MinutesBetween(StartDate, OldDate) mod 60;
  Secs  := SecondsBetween(StartDate, OldDate) mod 60;
  OutputText := Format('  %d days, %d hours, %d min, %d secs',
                       [Days, Hours, Mins, Secs]);
  WriteLn(OutputText);

end;

var
  BeginDate, EndDate: TDateTime;
begin
  BeginDate := Now;
  EndDate := BeginDate - 0.5;   // about 12 hours earlier
  ShowTimeDiff(BeginDate, EndDate);

  EndDate := BeginDate - 2.53724;  // Create date about 2 1/2 days earlier
  ShowTimeDiff(EndDate, BeginDate);

  EndDate := BeginDate - 5.75724;  // Create date about 5 3/4 days earlier
  ShowTimeDiff(BeginDate, EndDate);
  ReadLn;
end.
```

Produces the following output:

[image: Time differences]

Note that the reversal of parameter order between `DaysBetween` and `HoursBetween` is intentional to demonstrate that the functions always return positive values, so the order of the parameters isn't important. This is mentioned in the documentation.

Comment: I am getting the wrong number of seconds here... Put it in a timer and observe the output in real-time - you'll see it doesn't quite tick right, the seconds always appear under 30 seconds.

Comment: Yeah, the Seconds and Minutes are supposed to be `mod 60` not `mod 24`

Comment: It's been done. Must have happened while you posted your last comment. :)

Answer (score 5):

The problem is that when you subtract `Now` from `fDestDT` you expect to get difference between two dates, but you actually get another datetime value. As the values youre using are nearly the same, you get the "zero date" of the Delphi's [datetime](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/VCL/en/System.TDateTime) system, the 30. dets 1899. Thats why you get "30 Days" for `FormatDateTime('d', DT)+' Days'`.

Since the smallest amount youre intrested in is second I suggest you use [SecondsBetween](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/VCL/XE2/en/DateUtils.SecondsBetween) to get the difference between two timestamps and then divide it into parts like

```
diff := SecondsBetween(Now, fDestDT);
S:= IntToStr(diff mod 60)+' Seconds';
diff := diff div 60;
N:= IntToStr(diff mod 60)+' Minutes';
diff := diff div 60;
H:= IntToStr(diff mod 24)+' Hours';
diff := diff div 24;
D:= IntToStr(diff)+' Days';
```

Comment: Thanks, but the question has been modified since then, and is using a different approach now using DateUtils. +1 for the answer though.

Answer (score 3):

If you are using Delphi 2010 (I believe) or above, you can likely simplify your code and make it more clear by using the `TimeSpan.pas` unit, which contains a record that you can use to break out the amount of time in a given span of time.

Comment: No, I have Delphi 7, but is there any way I can sneak in this TimeSpan.pas unit? Sounds like it has exactly what I need...

Comment: Nick, the tags said Delphi 7. :) Jerry, you can get `TimeSpan` by upgrading your copy of Delphi. ;)

Comment: I have used 2010 and I still like 7 :P I guess I'll go get a copy of that unit and work it out for Delphi 7 :D

Comment: Ken -- Oops, you are right -- I looked in the question, but not the tags.

Answer (score 0):

I needed something more flexible that covers different formats, so I implemented `TTimeDiff` as:

```
uses
  SysUtils,
  DateUtils,
  StrUtils,
  Math;

type
  TTimeDiff = record
    type TTimeDiffFormat = (tdfFull, tdfSignificant, tdfAllNonZeros, tdfXNonZeros);
    procedure Init(const ANow, AThen: TDateTime);
    class function TimeDiff(const ANow, AThen: TDateTime): TTimeDiff; static;
    function ToString(const TimeDiffFormat: TTimeDiffFormat; const Delimiter: string = ', ';
      const NonZerosCount: Byte = 1): string;
    case Integer of
      0: (Years, Months, Days, Houres, Minutes, Seconds: Word);
      1: (Values: array[0..5] of Word);
  end;

{ TTimeDiff }

class function TTimeDiff.TimeDiff(const ANow, AThen: TDateTime): TTimeDiff;
begin
  Result.Init(ANow, AThen);
end;

procedure TTimeDiff.Init(const ANow, AThen: TDateTime);
begin
  Years := YearsBetween(ANow, AThen);
  Months := MonthsBetween(ANow, AThen) mod 12;
  Days := DaysBetween(IncMonth(Min(ANow, AThen), Years * 12 + Months), Max(ANow, AThen));
  Houres := HoursBetween(ANow, AThen) mod 24;
  Minutes := MinutesBetween(ANow, AThen) mod 60;
  Seconds := SecondsBetween(ANow, AThen) mod 60;
end;

function TTimeDiff.ToString(const TimeDiffFormat: TTimeDiffFormat; const Delimiter: string = ', ';
  const NonZerosCount: Byte = 1): string;
const
  Captions: array [0..5] of string = ('year', 'month', 'day', 'hour', 'minute', 'second');
var
  I: Integer;
  VisitedNonZeros: Byte;
begin
  Result := '';
  VisitedNonZeros := 0;
  for I := 0 to 5 do
  begin
    if Values[I] > 0 then
      Inc(VisitedNonZeros);
    if
      (TimeDiffFormat = tdfFull) or
      ((TimeDiffFormat = tdfSignificant) and (VisitedNonZeros > 0)) or
      ((TimeDiffFormat in [tdfAllNonZeros, tdfXNonZeros]) and (Values[I] > 0))
    then
    begin
      Result := Result + Format('%d %s%s%s', [Values[I], Captions[I], IfThen(Values[I] = 1, '', 's'), Delimiter]);
      if (TimeDiffFormat = tdfXNonZeros) and (VisitedNonZeros = NonZerosCount) then
        Break;
    end;
  end;
  Result := Copy(Result, 1, Length(Result) - Length(Delimiter));
end;
```

**`TTimeDiffFormat` explanation:**

- `tdfFull`: includes all parts regardless of their values (years, months, days, hours, minutes and seconds respectively).
- `tdfSignificant`: excludes LEADING zero-valued parts
- `tdfAllNonZeros`: excludes ALL zero-valued parts
- `tdfXNonZeros`: includes only first X non-zero valued parts, where X is set to 1 by default

**How to use:**

```
var
  ANow, AThen: TDateTime;
  Diff: TTimeDiff;
begin
  try
    ANow := DateUtils.EncodeDateTime(1993, 11, 3, 21, 22, 18, 0);
    AThen := DateUtils.EncodeDateTime(1993, 9, 21, 6, 21, 34, 0);
    Writeln('Difference between ');
    Writeln(FormatDateTime('YYYY/MM/DD HH:NN:SS', ANow), ' and');
    Writeln(FormatDateTime('YYYY/MM/DD HH:NN:SS', AThen), ' is:');
    Writeln('');

    Diff.Init(ANow, AThen);
    with Diff do
    begin

      Writeln(ToString(tdfFull));
      Writeln(ToString(tdfSignificant, ' and '));
      Writeln(TTimeDiff.TimeDiff(Athen, ANow).ToString(tdfSignificant), ' (inverted)');
      Writeln(ToString(tdfAllNonZeros));
      Writeln(ToString(tdfXNonZeros, ', ', 2));
      Writeln(ToString(tdfXNonZeros));
      readln;
    end;
  except
    on E: Exception do
      Writeln(E.ClassName, ': ', E.Message);
  end;
end.
```

**Results:**

```
Difference between
1993/11/03 21:22:18 and
1993/09/21 06:21:34 is:

0 years, 1 month, 13 days, 15 hours, 0 minutes, 43 seconds
1 month and 13 days and 15 hours and 0 minutes and 43 seconds
1 month, 13 days, 15 hours, 0 minutes, 43 seconds (inverted)
1 month, 13 days, 15 hours, 43 seconds
1 month, 13 days
1 month
```