# How to get difference of dates in Number of Days in Delphi?

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe2

I have two dates:
1. Feb 1, 2013
2. Now.
So there is a difference of 2 days in between 2 dates.
How can I get this difference of days in delphi programmatically?

Comment: I'd say the difference is three days (4−1=3), but you can always add/subtract one if you'd like.

Comment: See also: [`"Date/Time manipulation - friendly countdown string"`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8220649/576719).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use the `DaysBetween` function found in `DateUtils`:

```
var
  d1, d2: TDate;
begin

  d1 := EncodeDate(2013, 02, 01);
  d2 := EncodeDate(2013, 02, 04);

  ShowMessage(IntToStr(DaysBetween(d2, d1)));
```

Comment: I am picking one date as TDateTime from database, say Date1 : TDateTime, another is Now. Will ShowMessage(IntToStr(DaysBetween(Date1, Now))) work. Its giving me errors....

Answer (score 2):

The `TDateTime` is a float format where the integer part represents the number of days while the zecimal part represents the time (as a fraction of 24h).

So if you want to get a date that's tow days from today, you just add `2` to the original. If you you've got two dates and you want to compute the distance in days, use `DaysBetween` as Andreas suggests.

Example:

```
var D:TDateTime;
begin
  D := EncodeDate(2013, 2, 1);
  D := D + 2; // Adds two days.
end;
```

You can also use the `IncDay` function from `DateUtils` to do the same; Some would say it's more readable:

```
D := IncDay(D, 2);
```

Comment: For increased readability, there's also the `IncDay` function.

Comment: Too much pampering in may option, one should know how `TDateTime` works, and if they do, `IncDay` doesn't add much extra readability.

Comment: On the other hand, it brings harmony to an application that also makes use of the other options: `IncMonth`, `IncSecond`, etc, that aren't quite as easily replaced.

Comment: Yes - in future the implementation may be changed so the numeric version represents seconds rather than days as it is now. Adding two will then add two seconds, not two days. There is nothing that forces the VCL to use days. It could be changed in a flash, and then your code would break. Rather use IncDay so it doesn't break.